# I can't select elements inside of an array using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to respond to my clients. I tried putting all messages inside of an array and then looping over them but for some reason nothing happens when I get to the page. There are no errors either in puppeteer. I've used the console on the site and my selector does show the elements so I don't think I am using the wrong one.

Here's a picture of the elements.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0PeG.jpg

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
        ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
        args: [
            '--remote-debugging-port=9444',
            '--user-data-dir=D:/chrome-profiles/Snapchat1',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-default-browser-check',
            `--window-size=1920,1080`,

        ]
    });

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));


    const pages = await browser.pages();
    const page = pages[0];
    const fs = require('fs');

    let dir = "C:/Users/dresd/Desktop/alison";
    const rnd = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    const rndFile = () => `${dir}/${rnd(fs.readdirSync(dir))}`;
    const file = rndFile();

    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1200,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });

    await page.goto('https://web.snapchat.com/');
    await new Promise(function (resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, 2000) });

    const writeMessage = 'This product will be available in our store in 2 days. Please keep checking our story.'
    const messages = await page.$$('div[class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer"] > div[role="gridcell"]');

    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        const message = messages[i];
        await new Promise(function (resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, 2000) });
        await message.click()

    }
})();
```

Comment: I don't see that you ever use `file` or `writeMessage`.

Comment: I haven't used those yet but was planning to until I found out it's not clicking. I probably should've taken those out. Can this be causing an issue?

Comment: Probably not, but maybe you meant to and that was the problem. What's the error? Are you logged into snapchat in your browser? If so, I can't run the code and reproduce whatever problem you're having. What's supposed to happen when you click a message?

Comment: Yes, I am logged into my browser. It's not throwing an error. It just don't click into the chat windows for some reason. The chat windows are the grid cells I'm pretty sure the selector is correct but no idea why it doesn't do anything. It just sits there and never even closes.